# can't query multiple row of MySQL database in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to display what i want to select but i get only 1 row. How to solve it plz?
I only get the first row data but when i go to the do while in the second round it skip the loop and end the process.

```
     ListView1.Items.Clear()


        SQLstring = "SELECT * From record WHERE member_code like '" & u1 & "' "


        SQLConnection.Open()
        SQLcommand = New MySqlCommand(SQLstring, SQLConnection)
        SQLdatareader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()

        Do While SQLdatareader.Read()
            a = (SQLdatareader.Item("book_code").ToString())
            b = (SQLdatareader.Item("member_code").ToString())
            c = (SQLdatareader.Item("book_status").ToString())
            d = (SQLdatareader.Item("Borrow_date").ToString())
            f = (SQLdatareader.Item("Due_date").ToString())


            SQLdatareader.Close()
            SQLcommand.Dispose()
            SQLConnection.Close()

            SQLstring = "SELECT * From book WHERE book_code like '" & a & "' "
            SQLConnection.Open()
            SQLcommand = New MySqlCommand(SQLstring, SQLConnection)
            SQLdatareader = SQLcommand.ExecuteReader()
            Do While SQLdatareader.Read()
                g = (SQLdatareader.Item("book_name").ToString())
                h = (SQLdatareader.Item("book_writer").ToString())
                i = (SQLdatareader.Item("book_year").ToString())
            Loop




            Dim SQLlist As ListViewItem = ListView1.Items.Add(g)
            SQLlist.SubItems.Add(h)
            SQLlist.SubItems.Add(i)
            SQLlist.SubItems.Add(d)
            SQLlist.SubItems.Add(f)
            If dtNow > f Then
                Dim fine_amount = f.Subtract(dtNow)
                SQLlist.SubItems.Add(fine_amount)

            Else
                SQLlist.SubItems.Add("0")
            End If


        Loop
        SQLdatareader.Close()
        SQLcommand.Dispose()
        SQLConnection.Close()

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to have a % somewhere around your LIKE clause, so:

```
SQLstring = "SELECT * From record WHERE member_code like '" & u1 & "%' "
```

That would return all rows with a member_code that starts with your u1 variable.  If you just have the variable in there with no %, it will only return rows with exactly that member_code.

Also, not related to your question, but Google "Bobby Tables" and "SQL Injection".